# C# if statement readline must equal number

Tags: c#, string, int

I can't figure out what to put in brackets to make my program check if the input was number. I would like to return an error if not, and restart the process. Any suggestions?

```
bool running = true;

Console.Write("Enter the number of victims so we can predict the next murder, Sherlock: ");

while (running)
{
    victimCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (/*I want victimCount only to be accepted if it's a number*/)
    {
        Console.Write("\nThat's an invalid entry. Enter a correct number!: ");
    }
    else
    {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want victimCount only to be accepted if it's a number

You can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method instead. It returns `boolean` value that your value is a valid `int` or not.

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
int victimCount;
if(Int32.TryParse(s, out victimCount))
{
   // Your value is a valid int.
}
else
{
   // Your value is not a valid int.
}
```

`Int32.TryParse` method uses [`NumberStyles.Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) by default. That means your string can have;

- Leading `CurrentCulture`'s sign. ([`PositiveSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.positivesign.aspx) or [`NegativeSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign.aspx))
- Leading white spaces.
- Trailing white spaces

as a number stye.

Comment: @Zentie You are quite welcome.

Comment: what do I do if I want to do the same with a double, not an int? what do i put in instead of "Int32.TryParse"?

Comment: @Zentie You can use [`Double.TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Double.TryParse.aspx) in such a case. You need to change your `int victimCount;` to `double victimCount;` as well.

Comment: thanks once again, I've been looking for the method but I couldn't find it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int victimcount;
bool is Num = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out victimcount);

If `isNum` is true then the input is an integer. Use this for your check. At the same time, if the parse succeeds, the parsed value gets assigned to the `victimcount` variable (0 is assigned if it fails).
```